# Postgres pattern matching middle letters of a string

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

How would I match a name, such that one of the middle letters of the name must come from the word 'qwerty'(thus containing either of the letters 'q', 'w' , 'e', 'r', 't','y')?

I am curious how you can determine what the middle letters are, this would make use of some string count I assume.

What I have tried so far:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%(q|w|e|r|t|y)%'
```

Examples which would match:

```
Martens
Van Rossem
Frimout
Gates
```

Note: Middle letters in my exercise context means anything inbetween the first and last letter. I am still curious how one would match the 'median' letter of a string.

Comment: Do you mean `SIMILAR TO '%[qwerty]%'`? Could you share examples?

Comment: _middle letters_? Does that mean all letters except the first and the last? Even for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taumatawhakatangi%C2%ADhangakoauauotamatea%C2%ADturipukakapikimaunga%C2%ADhoronukupokaiwhen%C2%ADuakitanatahu?

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't support regular expressions. You need `similar to` or `~` if you want them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok yes that is correct, thank you, although I am still wondering how one would determine the median letters of a string

Comment: But what do you mean by "median letters"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew for example, 'hello' the middle letter would be 'l' (as per median formula n+1/2), "mynamejeff" would be m

Comment: You seem to want to match the same amount of chars on the left and right and then some chars in the middle, but this is not possible with PostgreSQL regex.

Comment: @jarlh that name XD lol

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok thanks thats good to know

Comment: I added another solution that may be close to what you want, but still does not fully adhere to the formula above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to match the same amount of chars on the left and right and then some chars in the middle, but this is not possible with PostgreSQL regex.

To find records that contain any of the characters in a pre-defined set, you may use [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) with a `%[qwerty]%` pattern:

```
SIMILAR TO '%[qwerty]%'
```

The `%` is a regular wildcard matching any text, and `[qwery]` is a bracket expression that matches a single character, either `q`, `w`, `e`, `r`, `t` or `y`.

If you just want to make sure these characters are not at the start and end, you may try an expression like

```
SIMILAR TO '[^qwerty]+[qwerty]+[^qwerty]+'
```

Keeping in mind that PostgreSQL *SIMILAR TO* patterns require the full string match, you will only get the records that start with 1+ chars other than `q`, `w`, `e`, `r`, `t`, `y` (`[^...]` is a *negated* bracket expression), then 1 or more required chars and then 1+ chars other than those.

Answer (score 2):

A different solution that is maybe simpler to write is to use PostgreSQL's regular expression matching operator `~`:

```
WHERE name ~ '.[qwerty].'
```

The pattern means: an arbitrary character, followed by any of the characters `qwerty`, followed by another arbitrary character.

Note that PostgreSQL translates `SIMILAR TO` expressions to regular expressions internally.